# How do I access outer scope variables from a callback in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I have a loop over some webpages and I want to check if they are available:

```
var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com'];
for(i in urls) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urls[i] })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is available.');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is NOT available.');
            });
}
```

but `urls[i]` is not available inside the callback functions how do I make is accessible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: "is not available inside the callback functions" --- what do you exactly mean? It **is** available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just based on that snippet, the `urls` variable should be available from within the functions.  *But* there are some other things that are going on...that are probably causing the problem.

Since those methods are asynchronous, they will execute at some later point.  So what *could* be happening is this:

```
var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com'];
for(i in urls) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urls[i] })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is available.');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is NOT available.');
            });
}
// some time later...
urls = null;
```

Even worse, `i` inside your callbacks is not going to be what you expect it to be.  The loop will execute first, and `i` will end up being (for both URLs) the last URL called.  This is a classic case of scoping issues with asynchronous functions.

By the time the functions get around to executing, `urls` could be null, or used for something else.  And, as already mentioned, `i` will not be what you expect it to be.  Try wrapping the `$http` call in an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com'];
for(i in urls) {
    (function(urls, i){
        // urls now "captured" in function-scope variable
        $http({method: 'GET', url: urls[i] })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is available.');
            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(urls[i] + ' is NOT available.');
            });
    })(urls, i);
}
```

I would also like to point out that it's considered a bad idea to use `for/in` on arrays: you should change that to using a regular for loop with an index variable, or use `.forEach`.  Here's how I would do it (which also, handily, eliminates the IIFE):

```
var urls = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.facebook.com'];
urls.forEach(function(url){
    $http({method: 'GET', url: url })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(url + ' is available.');
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(url + ' is NOT available.');
        });
});
```

Comment: It would be an "issue" with `i` not `urls`. "urls could be null" -- it's not possible in JS

Comment: It is possible, just as in my example.  But yes, there is ALSO a problem with `i`.

Comment: No, it's absolutely possible.  I just tried it to make sure I wasn't going crazy.  Sure enough, it's possible.  If `urls` is set to `null`, and THEN the callbacks execute, `urls` will be null inside them.  You try it.

Comment: PS: it is possible indeed. Not sure why I said that :-S

Answer (score 1):

You could get the url from "*config.url*" inside the callback.